# Taking $d$-th root of an element in the algebraic closure of $\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Suppose I have $\alpha \in \overline{\mathbb{Q}}$, the algebraic closure of $\mathbb{Q}$. Suppose I was interested in an element $\beta$ such that 
$\beta^d = \alpha$. Does there always exist $\beta \in \overline{\mathbb{Q}}$ such that this is satisfied for any $d \in \mathbb{N}$? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Yes. This is a consequence that the algebraic closure is always algebraically closed.

To show this, let $\beta$ be algebraic over $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$. Then there is some polynomial $f=x^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+...+a_0$ which has $\beta$ as a root, with $a_i \in \overline{\mathbb{Q}}$.

Recall that $\gamma$ is algebraic over $K$ if and only if the extension $K(\gamma)/K$ is finite. Now since the $a_i$ are algebraic over $\mathbb{Q}$, the extension $\mathbb{Q}(a_0,...,a_{n-1})/\mathbb{Q}$ is finite by the tower law. Hence $\mathbb{Q}(a_0,...,a_{n-1},\beta)/\mathbb{Q}$ is finite since it is at most $n$ times larger.

This means the subextension $\mathbb{Q}(\beta)/\mathbb{Q}$ must be finite which therefore implies $\beta$ is algebraic over $\mathbb{Q}$ and not just $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$

Therefore the polynomial $x^d-\alpha$ will always split over $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$ and hence you will find such a $\beta$.

Comment: is there a more explicit proof : a way for constructing a polynomial $P \in \mathbb{Q}[x]$ such that $P(\beta) = 0$ ?

Comment: @user1952009 take $g(X) =f(X^d)$

Comment: @Mathmo123 : sure, but I meant in the general case where $\beta$ is a root of $\sum_{n=0}^N a_n x^n,a_n \in \overline{Q}$